# Bootstrap affix() plugin having issue while scrolling the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap affix() plugin. I want the navbar to pin to the top of the screen when I scroll. here is what i have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/zncud7md/2/

The issue is the content below navbar shifts (tiny bit of inch downwards) when the affix class triggers in. I even tried adding the:
`#header.affix + #body { padding-top: 75px; }` that i found on other sources but didnt work for me.
I'm unable to find a way around this. Any ideas how can i prevent this issue??
Thanks!!

Comment: This looks like a working example: http://www.bootply.com/96188

Comment: What browsers? It seems to be working fine for me in Chrome without the CSS change you added up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap affix acts like sticky positioning so that if you scroll, you can have an element stick to a fixed position (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

Instead, you can simplify your code by setting your header position to fixed at top:0 and pad the top of your body.

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#body {
    padding-top: 75px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zncud7md/4/